# PostgreSQL deadlocks on two table locks

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking, deadlock

I am locking two different tables that have no interconnected columns, but I still get a deadlock.

Here is the server logs:

```
2013-10-22 15:16:19 EDT ERROR:  deadlock detected
2013-10-22 15:16:19 EDT DETAIL:  Process 26762 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 39913 of database 39693; blocked by process 26761.
    Process 26761 waits for RowExclusiveLock on relation 40113 of database 39693; blocked by process 26762. 
    Process 26762: lock table par_times in access exclusive mode
    Process 26761: INSERT INTO cached_float (entry_id, figure_type, value) VALUES (33225, 1, 54.759402056277075) RETURNING cached_float.id
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: More details please. Version of Postgres? Which tables do you lock and how?

Answer (score 3):

You can debug this by checking the numbers displayed here:

> Process 26762 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation **39913** of
>   database 39693; blocked by process 26761.
>   Process 26761 waits for RowExclusiveLock on relation **40113** of database
>   39693; blocked by process 26762.

Run in your database:

```
SELECT 39913::regclass AS tbl1, 40113::regclass AS tbl2
```

to see the involved tables. Also consider any triggers and possibly foreign key contraints on involved tables.

Generally: locking tables manually does not necessarily prevent deadlocks. It may be the *cause* of the the deadlock to begin with.